# how to automatically reload a page after jquery ajax is finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

here is my code for uploading some images on server
everything works except `success` - reloading the page after uploading is finished
I tried with another params - for example 20000 - without success
please help

```
inpfi.on('change', function(){
    var flist = inpfi[0].files;
    var fd = new FormData();
    for(let i = 0; i < flist.length; i++){fd.append('flist[]', flist[i]);}
    $.ajax({
        url: 'a_slike_up.php', 
        type: 'post',
        data: fd,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(){setInterval('location.reload()', 7000);}
    })
});
```

**update**

I tried plain js and it works
So I need the same - but in my jquery code

```
function handler_finito(e){
    location.href = location.href;
}

inpfi.on('change', function(){
    // ...
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.addEventListener("load", handler_finito, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "a_slike_up.php");
  ajax.send(fd);
});
```

Comment: Please explain why you think you need to reload the page or why you need ajax if you reload the page

Comment: @mplungjan - I simpy want to see the new uploaded images on the current page

Comment: There is NO reason to use AJAX if you reload the page. Why would you? That is a 
code smell. The page you submit to needs to return the data you need to update the page with. Alternatively if you need to go somewhere else and return the submit, then form and redirect back to the page. Absolutely no way do you want to use setInterval

Comment: Just put them there with script and return the OK stored in the success from the php.

Comment: See the dupe. There are many more examples of [image preview before ajax](https://www.google.com/search?q=preview+images+before+ajax+php+stackoverflow+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: @mplungjan - what a dupe ? I need reload AFTER ajax is finished, not while it is in proccess. Preview images doesn't solve because the new images should be clickable and triggering some additional code - which is not possible if they are  NOT really on server

Comment: So return the image location instead. Save the image on the server and return the location and change the image on the client: `success: function(data) { document.getElementById('imageResult').src = data.imageSource},` where you return `echo "{ \"imageSource\":\"/images/$imageName\" }';` for example

Comment: Like [this answer does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19557692/save-a-image-in-the-folder-and-getting-the-image-name-using-ajax)

Comment: @mplungjan - plain js has this - `ajax.addEventListener("load", handler_fn, false).` I tried and it works. So I want the same, but in my jquery code

Comment: That does not fit your requirements. You need to post, so post and return the information needed to load the image again

Comment: @mplungjan - this perfectly fits my task. See my update, pls

Comment: `success: function(){ location.reload(true)}` or `success:handler_finito,` - it is still not what I would do at all. No reason what so ever to reload after ajax or use ajax if you plan a reload. Instead submit the form without any script and do this in `a_slike_up.php`: `header("Location: $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']"); die();`

Answer (score -2):

use setTimeout function instead of setInteval:

```
success: function(data) {
    setTimeout(function(){
       location.reload();
}, 7000);
```